# Is resetting the command buffer faster than setting an uniform buffer?

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to learn Vulkan (mostly from [vulkan-tutorial.com](https://vulkan-tutorial.com)) as I write a mixed graphics/compute application (I need to render a depth buffer and perform some computations over it, no display). I am almost rendering my first (depth) image, and all I need to do is figure out how to pass a single `vec4` as the sole parameter to my vertex shader (besides the position attribute).

All places I read says push constants are faster than uniforms, so they seemed the obvious choice for my parameter, but it seems that I need to reset the command buffer at every rendered image in order to change my push constants with `vkCmdPushConstants()`, while with uniforms, I can keep my command buffer fixed, and simply update the mapped memory region (and flush, if not coherent) before submitting my render task with `vkQueueSubmit()`.

Is rewriting the whole command buffer really faster than a mapped memory write? Or people saying push parameters are faster are assuming the command buffer will be rebuilt at every rendered image, so most of the cost would already be paid anyway?

And finally, can I update the push constant in another command buffer, smaller, submitted previously and sync with the other command buffer with a semaphore? (I guess not, but it is not clear to me for how long a constant pushed is valid, nor for how long a pipeline remains bound, for that matter.) If possible, is this a good approach?

EDIT: Not, that is not possible, just found [here](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.26.0/linux/vkspec.chunked/ch05.html) that:

> Each command buffer manages state independently of other command buffers.

and

> When a command buffer begins recording, all state in that command
>   buffer is undefined.

thus my problem remains.

Answer (score 4):

> Is rewriting the whole command buffer really faster than a mapped memory write?

That's the wrong question. You are not taking into account what it actually takes to modify memory such that the GPU can use it.

OK, so you've got this command buffer that reads uniforms from some memory. And you want to use it in two separate frames. But you want to change the memory between frames.

Well, you cannot write to that memory until the first frame has finished reading from it. So you need the CB to set an event after the last time it reads the uniform. And after submitting the CB for that frame, you need to wait on that event on the CPU before you can write your data (let alone submit the next frame's worth of data).

So that's CPU/GPU synchronization. That's not good, for GPU performance or CPU performance. The GPU may run out of work because the CPU had to do such synchronization, and the CPU may just be sitting there doing nothing.

Rebuilding most command buffers is the typical way Vulkan applications work.

Comment: Suppose I can have N frames rendered simultaneously: I could either rewrite and submit the command buffer N times, or have N different command buffers bound to N different memory areas for the uniform. In both I would need N fences to know when I can submit the next frame, so I don't really see a difference here.

Comment: "*Suppose I can have N frames rendered simultaneously*" Why would you have more than one frame rendering simultaneously? And in any case, you merely need N+1 buffers, with N+1 regions of memory. And you use semaphores to do synchronization, not events, since you're synchronizing based on when the submission itself is done.

Comment: I just generalized, you said "And you want to use it in two separate frames.", I generalized to N, it is the same problem: I can solve it by allocating one uniform buffer for rendered frame. Specifically, in I my application, all the frames I need are known beforehand (i.e. not time dependent, like in an interactive application), so I could theoretically queue any number of frames I need simultaneously.

Comment: *"In both I would need N fences to know when I can submit the next frame, so I don't really see a difference here."* The difference is in synchronization. You still need to perform it, You still need N fences to know when You can reuse (re-record) or destroy a command buffer. But with N frames You can perform this synchronization while GPU is still doing its job. Even if You submit those N command buffers together, there is a very high chance that the first one will be finished much earlier than the last one. So You can reuse it without blocking the GPU.

Comment: @Ekzuzy Are you saying I can't perform the synchronization while the GPU is still doing its job if I use N uniform buffers (instead of push constants)? I know what uniform buffer is used by what command buffer, so if one command buffer is done, I can write its corresponding uniform buffer to resubmit. The GPU is still working with the other command buffers. What is the difference?

Comment: @lvella The difference is that if You have only one command buffer, than You have to wait until it is fully process by the GPU. Only the You can re-record it or update data. This causes GPU to wait so You lose performance. If You have greater number of resources, You can perform synchronization the way You describe it. But with N resources, GPU is still performing its job while You update data and/or re-record other command buffers.

Comment: But I want to know the difference between: a) rewriting the command buffer for each new frame just to update the push constant, and b) updating an uniform variable, reusing the same command buffer bound to that uniform.

Comment: @lvella: You've been told the difference. In one case, you have to synchronize your modifications of the uniform with the completion of the CB. In the other case, you can create a *new command buffer* and not have to synchronize with anything.